# MissingMethodException when calling method inside another

Tags: groovy

I am trying to call a method inside another and I am getting a `MissingMethodException`. My code looks something like this:

```
class Foo {
  static def bar {
    //do stuff
    return something
  }
  static def baz { myVar=false ->
    def something = bar()
    //do stuff w/something
  } 
}
Foo.baz()
```

and this is the error I get: `Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Foo$__clinit__closure6.bar() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

I found that I can fix this error if I define `baz` like this instead:

```
static def baz { myVar=false ->
  def something = this.bar()
  //do stuff w/something
}
```

but if I do that, my IDE tells me that this is an `Unnecessary qualified reference`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax in your snippet is wrong. Either you wanted `static def bar = {}` or `static def bar() {}`.

If you wanted `bar` to be a method, then there is no error:

```
class Foo {
  static bar() { 'something' }

  static baz = { myVar=false ->
    def something = bar()
    return something + "!"
  } 
}

assert Foo.baz() == "something!"
```

If you want `bar` to be a closure (i.e. `bar = {}`) then to invoke `bar` from `baz` you need to put the class name first:

```
class Foo {
  static bar = { 'something' }

  static baz = { myVar=false ->
    def something = Foo.bar()
    return something + "!"
  } 
}

assert Foo.baz() == "something!"
```